# Error 500.19 when debugging Azure web role on IIS Express

Tags: debugging, web-config, iis-express, azure-web-roles

I have a MVC 3.0 web application running on an Azure cloud service as a web role. When debugging the application under Visual Studio 2013, if  I delay too long between breakpoints, the web role shuts down and IIS Express 8.0 responses an error 500.19 to the browser.

I have set up the project to run in IIS Express and the emulator express. When the Azure emulator starts, it creates a file named *applicationHost.config* inside the folder:

*C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\some random guid>\temp\temp\RoleTemp*

I set a breackpoint in a controller of the MVC application. Then if the debugging session takes more than one minute (more or less), The above file is deleted and I get an error 500.19 in my browser. After that, I can't acces to the app because in every request I got the same error.

After inspecting other files in the avobe folder, I've found a log named *WaHostBootstraper.log* and the last lines of the log are:

```
[00010272:00004636, 2015/01/27, 19:59:29.924, INFO ] Role host process registered.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:30.350, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:30.350, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:30.850, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:30.850, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:31.350, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:31.350, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:31.851, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:31.851, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:32.352, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:32.352, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:32.853, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:32.853, INFO ] Client reported status 1.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:33.353, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:33.379, INFO ] Client reported status 0.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:33.880, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:33.887, INFO ] Client reported status 0.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:48.889, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 19:59:48.916, INFO ] Client reported status 0.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 20:00:03.917, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 20:00:03.922, INFO ] Client reported status 0.
[00010272:00006280, 2015/01/27, 20:00:18.923, INFO ] Getting status from client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
[00010272:00005408, 2015/01/27, 20:01:33.926, INFO ] Sending shutdown notification to client WaIISHost.exe (5056).
```

I'm using Azure SDK 2.5, Azure emulator 2.8.

Comment: I have the same problem when using Azure SDK 2.7